# line chart issues in windows forms application with c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, graph, data-visualization

i am using windows form application to design a graphical user interface for analyzing the data.
i am using line chart to plot the data .i am able to receive the data properly and able to plot the data on graph. i have attached the image of the line chart.

[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDOtx.jpg)

As i increase the X(gain) value the Y(Vout) value also increases which is proper ,but as i decrease the X value loops are formed in the graph how can i remove this loops.

**Code**

```
 private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            switch (comboBox_Solution.Text)
            {
                case "1":
                    chart1.Series["Solution1"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    
                    break;
                case "2":
                    chart1.Series["Solution2"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    chart1.Series["Solution3"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    chart1.Series["Solution4"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    chart1.Series["Solution5"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    break;
                case "6":
                    chart1.Series["Solution6"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    break;
                case "7":
                    chart1.Series["Solution7"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    break;
                case "8":
                    chart1.Series["Solution8"].Points.AddXY(gain, Vout);
                    break;


            }

        }
```

complete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Data_logger
{
    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string serialDataIn;
        Int32 indexOfA;
        Int32 indexOfB;
        string VoltageText,VoltageGraph;
        string GainText,GainGraph;
        Int32 Vout;
       string time;
        Int32 gain_receive;
        string SolutionText ;
        int checkBoxCount;
        






        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button_open.Enabled = true;
            button_close.Enabled = false;
            button_Gain.Enabled = false;
            button_Gain_Select.Enabled = true;

            verticalProgressBar_StatusCom.Value = 0;
            comboBox_BaudRate.Text = "9600";
            comboBox_Solution.Text = "1";

           
            label6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
            
           
          

            chart1.Series["Solution1"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Solution2"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Solution3"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Solution4"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Solution5"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Solution6"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Solution7"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Solution8"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);


        }

        private void comboBox_ComPort_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] portlists = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox_ComPort.Items.Clear();
            comboBox_ComPort.Items.AddRange(portlists);

          

        }

        private void button_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox_ComPort.Text;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_BaudRate.Text);
                serialPort1.Open();

                timer1.Start();
                label5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
               


                chart1.Series["Solution1"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series["Solution2"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series["Solution3"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series["Solution4"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series["Solution5"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series["Solution6"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series["Solution7"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.Series["Solution8"].Points.Clear();






                button_open.Enabled = false;
                button_close.Enabled = true;
                button_Gain.Enabled = true;
                button_Gain_Select.Enabled = true;

                verticalProgressBar_StatusCom.Value = 100;
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Connected");

            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               
                serialPort1.Close();

                button_open.Enabled = true;
                button_close.Enabled = false;
                button_Gain.Enabled = false;
                button_Gain_Select.Enabled = true;
               
                verticalProgressBar_StatusCom.Value = 0;
                timer1.Stop();
               
                MessageBox.Show("Disconnected");

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            timer1.Start();

        }
        private void button_Gain_Select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox_GainSet.Clear();
            int item_count = checkedListBox_Gain_Multi.CheckedItems.Count;
            for (int j = 0; j < checkedListBox_Gain_Multi.CheckedItems.Count; j++)
            {
                if(j<=(item_count-2))
                {
                    textBox_GainSet.Text += checkedListBox_Gain_Multi.CheckedItems[j] + ",";

                }
                else
                {
                    textBox_GainSet.Text += checkedListBox_Gain_Multi.CheckedItems[j];

                }

            }
        }

    

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            { 
                try
                {

                    serialPort1.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                }
            }

        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            serialDataIn = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ProcessData));
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
        }

        private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            switch (comboBox_Solution.Text)
            {
                case "1":
                    chart1.Series["Solution1"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    
                    break;
                case "2":
                    chart1.Series["Solution2"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    chart1.Series["Solution3"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    chart1.Series["Solution4"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    chart1.Series["Solution5"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    break;
                case "6":
                    chart1.Series["Solution6"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    break;
                case "7":
                    chart1.Series["Solution7"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    break;
                case "8":
                    chart1.Series["Solution8"].Points.AddXY(gain_receive, Vout);
                    break;


            }

        }

       

        private void ProcessData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                indexOfA = Convert.ToInt32(serialDataIn.IndexOf("A"));
                indexOfB = Convert.ToInt32(serialDataIn.IndexOf("B"));

                VoltageText = serialDataIn.Substring(0, indexOfA);
                VoltageGraph = serialDataIn.Substring(0, indexOfA);
                GainText = serialDataIn.Substring(indexOfA + 1, (indexOfB - indexOfA) - 1);
                GainGraph = serialDataIn.Substring(indexOfA + 1, (indexOfB - indexOfA) - 1);

                textBox_Voltage.Text = VoltageText;
                textBox_Voltage.Refresh();
                textBox_Gain.Text = GainText;
                textBox_Gain.Refresh();
              
                Vout = Convert.ToInt32(VoltageGraph);
                gain_receive = Convert.ToInt32(GainGraph);
                time = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                SolutionText = comboBox_Solution.Text;
                addRecord(time, VoltageText, GainText, SolutionText, @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\MyLab\data1.csv");
               
              

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
            
      
        }

        private void button_Gain_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Actions performed when gain Select button is pressed
            try
            {
                checkBoxCount = checkedListBox_Gain_Multi.CheckedItems.Count;
                GainText = textBox_GainSet.Text;
                serialPort1.Write(checkBoxCount + "," + GainText);           // a string foramt of G1,G2,G3,\n will be send to the serial port
                textBox_GainSet.Clear();
                // gain = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_GainSet.Text);
                /* gain++;
                 if (gain > 8)
                 {
                     gain = 0;
                 }
                 textBox_GainSet.Text = Convert.ToString(gain);
                */

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }

        }

        public static void addRecord(string time , string VoltageText, string GainText, string SolutionText, string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter File = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@filepath, true))
                {
                    File.WriteLine(time + "," + VoltageText + "," + GainText + "," + SolutionText);
                }
                 
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);

            }
        }
        private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.Interval = 0;

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);

                label7.Text = "pixel X position " + chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X).ToString();
                label8.Text = "pixel y position " + chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y).ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);


            }

            

            



        }
    }
}
```

As i increase the gain value form 1 to 8 the i get the corresponding value on Y axis but when i go back form 8 to 1 i get a loop in the graph which i have marked in th image . i want to make changes in the code that i go back from to 8 to 1 there shouldn't be any loop forming in the graph.

Comment: can you provide the related code about your current chart? Only with the code you provided, we can not reproduce your problem. Or What is your final result you want to get?

Comment: As i increase the gain value form 1 to 8 the i get the corresponding value on Y axis but when i go back form 8 to 1 i get a loop in the graph which i have marked in th image . i want to make changes in the code that i go back from to 8 to 1 there shouldn't be any loop forming in the graph. i have also uploaded the whole code @JackJJun-MSFT